# My JVM crahes when i run my program

Tags: java, jvm

I have written a program to process packets. The program runs well if its run alone but when i integrate it to my main project the jvm crashes and shows the below result. What is the problem?

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d7dcf6e, pid=4328, tid=4068
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0_16-b02 mixed mode, sharing)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x9cf6e]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid4328.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a bug in the jpcap API. The error is solved if you use the getPacket method instead of the loopPacket or processPacket methods.

Answer (score 3):

You've hit a bug in the JVM.  So you should file a bug report.  They will probably want you to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that causes the crash.

Answer (score -1):

Check the Heap size for the Program, there might be problem with that.
Check for the network authentication, if your application accessign some other network resources

Comment: You're not supposed to get an access violation just because you run out of memory.